# Converting an enum into a Dictionary<T, int>

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert an `Enum` into a `Dictionary(Of T, Integer)`. I can get a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` but how do I get the key to be an `Enum` and not a `String`?

**CODE**

Sub Main

```
Dim returnString As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)
Dim returnEnum As KeyValuePair(Of Type, Integer)

    returnString = New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)([Enum].GetName(GetType(ResponseCode), 3), 3)
    returnEnum = New KeyValuePair(Of Type, Integer)(GetType(ResponseCode), 3)

    'Tesing with LinqPad
    returnString.Dump()
    returnEnum.Dump()
End Sub

Enum ResponseCode
    Found = 1
    Create = 2
    Update = 3
End Enum
```

Here is the output using LinqPad

**OUTPUT**

```
returnString
KeyValuePair<String,Int32>
Update, 3 

returnEnum
KeyValuePair<Type,Int32> 
typeof(ResponseCode), 3
```

Comment: This code is VB, yet you've tagged C#...

Comment: What is the point?  `EnumVar.ToString()` on an enum gives you the name/text.

Comment: The enum value is an `int`, the enum type is `ResponseCode`.  You cannot have a Dictionary<T, int> because the type of all your enum values is still `ResponseCode` and you'll have duplicate keys in the dictionary.

Comment: @maccettura : Actually the enum type is implicitly `Integer` (C#: `int`), however the enum _**name**_ is `ResponseCode`. In VB.NET enums are declared as: `[access modifier] Enum [name] As [type]`.

Comment: Adding to @Plutonix's question, "What is the point?", you then pass in the Enum value to the dictionary to return ... the same value. So you have made a 1:1 dictionary mapping. What is the point?